# "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class" in Spring Boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I am using to configure spring boot with an external YAML configuration and CMD.

**-> application.yml file**

```
spring:
  profiles: integration-test
  datasource:
    driverClassName: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME}
    url: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL}
    username: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME}
    password: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD}
```

**-> cmd**

```
mvn clean install
```

**-> Result**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot load driver class: ${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME}
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: What driver are you using? Did you add its dependency?

Comment: Hello! driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

Comment: <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.15</version>
        </dependency>

Comment: I want to pass the name and all vars in cmd when in execute project jar

Comment: Please paste the exact error you're getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use the syntax `${}`, you are actually telling Spring Boot to use the value of the property whose name is between brackets. In your case, Spring Boot tries to resolve the property `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`. When it fails, it uses the string as is, which leads to the error you mentioned, since no driver exists under the name `${SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME}`.

To solve the issue, you can either :

1. replace the `${}` by the real values, e.g. `driverClassName: org.postgresql.Driver` and do the same for the other properties (`url`, `username` and `password`)
2. provide properties `SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME`,`SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` and the two others. These can passed in the command line with `-D` options (e.g. -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver) or through environment variables. You can look at spring [Boot documentation for more details](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: Okey, it is helpful

Answer (score 0):

Pass those variables in your launch configuration of your program or at commandline when you run your app with `java YourMainClass`, e.g.

`java -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=<full_qualified_name_of_your_jdbc_driver_class> -DSPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=<jdbc_url> YourMainClass`

also pass the other two variables the same way, username & password!

your can even set those enviroment variables on OS level, so you don't have to set them each time you start your application...

if your using Spring Boot also have a look at this one: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html